# How to divide the sum of a column under two different conditions?

Tags: sql, hive

Say I have three columns, one for the date, one for the values, and one for some category. I can get the sum of the values grouped by the date with the following code

```
SELECT date, SUM(values) from table WHERE category = condition GROUP BY date
```

And I can get the sum of all the values with

```
SELECT date, SUM(values) from table GROUP BY date
```

I want the values for the SUM(values) column to be equal to the (SUM(values) where category = condition) / (SUM(values)), or in plain words, the proportion of the values with that condition. Is there a way to do this in one query? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `CASE` condition inside aggregate functions like `SUM`.

```
SELECT 
date, 
(
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = condition Then values ELSE 0)
  / SUM(Values)
) as proportion
from table 
GROUP BY date
```